# Visual Studio Modifications to a Project not Updating the .exe File in \bin

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am quite new to Visual Studio (Express).  I made a project and then put a shortcut on my Desktop to the .exe file.  Later I made some changes to the project which are all visible when I run the project in Visual Studio using CTRL + F5.  However, the .exe file that is pointed to by my Desktop shortcut still runs the old version.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Check your build configuration - is it Debug or Release? What is the path for the shortcut vs. your project /bin path?

Comment: The shortcut might point to the Debug version, while you are building the Release version, or vice versa.

Comment: The shortcut is to the \bin\Release directory.  I can't seem to find my build configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the "Rebuild" action instead of "Build". Sometimes .NET compiler gets confused what has changed - "Rebuild forces a recompile of the solution instead of just the "changed" files.

Comment: I had changed the namespace so that it was different from the one on the build tab.  Making them the same and rebuilding did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

by rightclicking on your project in solution explorer, going to properties and then going to the build tab you can choose your output path. bin\Debug\ is the default which is probably where your newly built .exe is going

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for the issue. What I did was removing the `.exe` files present in the `/bin/Debug` directory. The rebuild will automatically generate the `.exe` file again.